# Can Udyr Max out all his skills?

Tags: league-of-legends

If **Udyr** gets all his skills at the start of the game, can they all max out? If not, what are the limits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No he cannot.  Just like every champion he gets 1 ability pt per level.  He has 4 skills that can be maxed to level 5 which means he has to choose which abilities he wants to focus and max and which he is willing to give up.

Look at the skill order section of this guide http://www.solomid.net/guides.php?g=10962.  You can see he chooses Tiger Stance to not max.

Answer (score 2):

No, because he still only gets 18 levels, meaning he can max out 5 of his skills, and take the last to level 3, or max two and take the last two to level 4 (5+5+5+3=18, or 5+5+4+4=18).

Comment: it is usually best for udyr to pick one skill to level last depending on your build so that his other skills are more powerful early.  It is rarely advised to have two 4 pt skills at lvl 18.

Comment: Yeah, I agree.  It is, however, an option that I thought was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

Actually in the current patch it is possible to max out Udyrs skills, but only if you run an Cleptomancy rune build. This rune has the chance to drop you an "Elixier of Skill" while you attack enemy champions. This elixier provides you with additional skill points when used

Comment: How many total skill points would Udyr be able to get if he uses this rune?

Comment: It would depend on luck, but I have yet to see more than one extra skill point dropping from that while playing Ezreal.